# Empty values when assign a new column to an existing Datafram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

when I try to make a new column to add to an existing dataframe , the new column only has empty values . However, when print "result" before assigns it to the dataframe it works fine! and thus I get this weird error of max arg!

> ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

I'm using mplfinance to plot the data

strategy.py

```
def moving_average (self, df , i): 

    signal = df['sma20'][i]*1.10

    if (df['sma20'][i] > df['sma50'][i]) & (signal >df['Close'][i]):
        return df['Close'][i]
    else:
        return None
```

trading.py

```
for i in range(0, len(df['Close'])-1):

    result = strategy.moving_average(df , i)
    print(result)

    df['buy']= result

    df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')

    apd = mpf.make_addplot(df['buy'],scatter=True,marker='^')
    mpf.plot(df, type='candle', addplot=apd)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: @AMC I have at the beginning! 

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: That’s not all the output though, no?

Comment: no, it's and when I searched I found out it's because df['buy'] column has nan values only. that's why I ask why it returns empty values!

Comment: Pardon? I was just asking about the error, there's generally more information which comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very small amount of information here, and on your comment

> "because df['buy'] column has nan values only."

I'm going to *guess* that your problem is that `strategy.moving_average()` is returning `None` instead of `nan` when there is no signal.

There is a big difference between `None` and `nan`.  (The main issue is that `nan` supports math, whereas `None` does not; and as a general rule plotting packages always do math).

I suggest you `import numpy as np` and then in `strategy.moving_average()`

change `return None`

to **`return np.nan`**.

---

**ALSO** just saw another problem.
You are only assigning a single value to `df['buy']`.
You need to take it out of the loop.
I suggest **initialize `result` as an empty list before the loop**
then:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(df['Close'])-1):

    result.append(strategy.moving_average(df , i))
    print(result)

df['buy']= result

df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8')

apd = mpf.make_addplot(df['buy'],scatter=True,marker='^')
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', addplot=apd)
```